# Slow wordpress query time

Tags: mysql, database

i'm working on MU wordpress site, i have problem in query which take too much time to execute.

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.blog_id = '1'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'post_tag' 
AND wp_terms.slug IN ('rate') 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

This query which is executed by wordpress, it take 30-40 sec to execute which is too much.

- wp_posts : 4,00,000 rows
- wp_terms : 2,50,000 rows
- wp_term_relationship : 2,30,000 rows
- wp_term_taxonomy : 2,60,000 rows

I have already indexed the columns (that are used).

Comment: `WHERE 1=1`? Why are you using this?

Comment: what is 4,00,000? 400000?

Comment: show us the `EXPLAIN` output

Comment: @Kasyx:that's just syntax-sugar to make you able to add `AND` to all `WHERE` parts. No worries. @OP: can you add the `EXPLAIN` for the query?

Comment: More RAM or an SSD + heavier caching?

Comment: this query generating from wordpress, thats why it having WHERE 1=1

Comment: 4,00,000 number of rows in tables..

Comment: query display all posts regarding category or tag from wp_posts table.

Comment: its run on 16GB RAM. :P

Comment: The output of an explain is pretty much essential to give you any useful guidance.

Comment: I want all posts related to tag "rate".

Comment: No, do an EXPLAIN of the query. If you execute your query with EXPLAIN at the front of it then it will give you details of how the tables are joined, etc, rather than actually executing the query. I will add a reply below.

Comment: SIMPLE wp_term_taxonomy ref PRIMARY,taxonomy,term_taxonomy_id taxonomy 98 const 201260 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort SIMPLE wp_terms ref PRIMARY,term_id,slug,slug_2 term_id 8 jj_demo_30052013.wp_term_taxonomy.term_id 6 Using where SIMPLE wp_term_relationships ref term_taxonomy_id,object_id term_taxonomy_id 8 jj_demo_30052013.wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id 14 SIMPLE wp_posts eq_ref PRIMARY,type_status_date,ID_2,blog_id,post_status PRIMARY 12 jj_demo_30052013.wp_term_relationships.object_id,const 1 Using where

Answer (score 0):

Try and explain as follows.

Paste the following into phpmyadmin and execute it:-

```
EXPLAIN SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.blog_id = '1'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'post_tag' 
AND wp_terms.slug IN ('rate') 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Then copy the results of that and paste them into your original question. It will give details of which keys were used in which tables, etc.

Comment: SIMPLE wp_term_taxonomy ref PRIMARY,taxonomy,term_taxonomy_id taxonomy 98 const 201260 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

SIMPLE wp_terms ref PRIMARY,term_id,slug,slug_2 term_id 8
jj_demo_30052013.wp_term_taxonomy.term_id 6 Using where

SIMPLE wp_term_relationships ref term_taxonomy_id,object_id
term_taxonomy_id 8 jj_demo_30052013.wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
14

SIMPLE wp_posts eq_ref PRIMARY,type_status_date,ID_2,blog_id,post_status
PRIMARY 12 jj_demo_30052013.wp_term_relationships.object_id,const
1
Using where

Comment: Looking at the results of that MySQL is taking the table wp_term_taxonomy and joining others to it using a poor key. I would suggest adding a key to wp_posts covering the fields blog_id, post_type and post_status (index needs to be for all 3 columns, not 3 separate indexes each on 1 column). Hopefully that will push it to using wp_posts as the first table. If that doesn't work then try using a STRAIGHT_JOIN instead of INNER JOIN (it forces the order the tables are joined in).

Comment: So i will drop separated indexes for each column and main as you told.

Comment: No real need to drop the existing indexes, just add a new one that covers several columns. MySQL will only use one index when accessing a table and can't combine them. So if on the wp_posts table you had an index on blog_id, another index on post_type and another index on post_status MySQL will only use one of them. Adding an extra index on all 3 columns would mean that all 3 values could be used to look up matching records.

Answer (score 0):

For future, you can always re-edit your post and add content like the dump of an EXPLAIN (sql statement) as opposed to dumping into a comment.

The query itself looks pretty direct and your indexes per the explain appear ok, but for the WP_Posts table, I might change (or just add another index) based on

```
( Blog_ID, Post_Type, Post_Status, ID, Post_Date )
```

This way, it matches the criteria first, then the ID for optimizing the GROUP BY, and finally the Post_Date for Order By clause.

Next, so the engine doesn't try to work by some other reference table first, have you  tried adding the keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" to it...

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN wp_posts.* ... rest of query
```

Another alternative I would consider is to pre-query just the IDs via distinct, then join back to the WP_Posts table... I don't know if its choking on you doing a SELECT * and grouping by just the ID.

```
SELECT
      wp_posts.* 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT 
              WP.ID
           from 
              wp_posts WP
                 INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships WPR
                    ON WP.ID = WPR.object_id
                    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy WPTT
                       ON WPR.term_taxonomy_id = WPTT.term_taxonomy_id
                       INNER JOIN wp_terms WPT
                          ON WPTT.term_id = WPT.term_id
           WHERE 
                  1 = 1 
              AND WP.blog_id = '1'
              AND WP.post_type = 'post' 
              AND WP.post_status = 'publish'
              AND WPTT.taxonomy = 'post_tag' 
              AND WPT.slug IN ('rate') 
           GROUP BY 
              WP.ID 
           ORDER BY 
              WP.post_date DESC 
           LIMIT
              0, 20 ) JustIDs
      JOIN WP_Posts
         on JustIDs.ID = WP_Posts.ID
```